# Base64 encoded image string into Oracle BLOB database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio, blob

I am tasked with taking a base64 encoded image and storing it into an Oracle SQL database as a blob.

I have the string of the base64 encoded image but it doesn't look like what gets exported from the sql database column blob.

When I export the blob from the database into an xml it looks like so:

image="FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFFE003B43524541544F523A2067642D6A7065672076312E3020287573696E6720494A47204A50454720763830292C207175616C697479203D2039300AFFDB0043000302020302020303030304030304050805050404050A070706080C0A0C0C0B0A0B0B0D0E12100D0E110E0B0B101610111314...."

Does anyone know what conversion this is? or is this type of conversion possible in C#?

Any help is greatly appreciated, or just a push in the right direction would be awesome also!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Image=** is showing you the raw file in Hexadecimal.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thanks a ton, this points me in the direction I need!